# How can I get rid of the 'wl_80211_attach Reg CFG80211 Phy' warning during boot?

Tags: 12.04, wireless

When I switch on my laptop a message on a black screen appears :

> [] INFO@wl_80211_attach Reg CFG80211 Phy.

It stays for only 1 sec , even if I try to type anything it will disappear after 1 sec and go to the login screen.

Is it something to do with wireless because my wi-fi network doesn’t show up in the list. After when I connect the Ethernet cable and refresh on my ISP website, does my wi-fi connection gets established.

`lspci` shows:

> 0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

and `rfkill list` returns:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: I have this warning and can connect without an issue to my wireless networks, lspci shows `Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n` I have a different adapter though.

Comment: I am a newbie linux user and I don't know much about it. Should I install the adapter you are using and if yes , how?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than the Broadcom STA driver, I think you will have much better luck with the native driver and its firmware. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```

It may take a reboot. Does your wireless perform better now?

Comment: Hi there I put in the first two commands into the terminal and both of these commands did the required function. But the 3rd and 4th command gave the following message :                                                               jerin@jerin-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo modprobe -r wl
FATAL: Module wl not found.
jerin@jerin-Inspiron-1545:~$ sudo modprobe b43

Comment: After a reboot, does your wireless now work as expected?

Comment: Yes I rebooted but the same thing happens. Now I am not able to see any wireless networks and my wireless is not working. But the net through Ethernet cable is working fine. Oh

Comment: I typed the following command into the terminal: sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source Now the wireless networks are available. But to connect to my own network the same procedure happens. I have to go to my ISP's website refresh , only then does the wifi gets connected to my own network. It's been quite some days and I am struggling with this. Ubuntu is not a deal breaker but its a matter of convenience.